# How do I place two figures into a column on a two-column document?

Tags: floats, two-column

I wanna to place two figures (one with two subfigures) into a column on a two-column document, as shown below.

[image]

I tried `\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}`, but got this,

[image]

I also tried `\begin{multicols}{1} ... \end{multicols}`, but got nothing.

Here is my source code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{todonotes}      % create Placeholder for missing figure
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{figure*}[h]%[pbth]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Fig. 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Fig. 1}
\end{figure*}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{multicols}{1}
\begin{figure}%[h]%[pbth]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Subfigure 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \missingfigure[figwidth=\textwidth]{}
        \caption{Subfigure 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Fig. 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%{0.3\textwidth}
    \missingfigure[figwidth=.3\textwidth]{}
    \caption{Fig. 2}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place a combination of ordinary figures and subfigures by making use of the minipage environment.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
\minipage[t]{0.66\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Bob}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Bob's brother}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is a description that's too long to fit on one line.}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
~ % some horizontal spacing, can be done in different ways
\minipage[t]{0.33\linewidth}%
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{This is a description that's even longer, some would say that it's even too long. However, it shows that figure vertical alignment is not affected.}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image: figures and subfigures aligned]

As you can see figures are aligned horizontally, independently of caption length. This is because I used the placement modifier top [t] for the minipages and subfigures. Obviously, this relatively easy solution works out best if images have the same size, because the top of figures is aligned instead of the bottom.

Comment: Seems like from OP's first image, the caption for Fig. 2 should be in line with the main caption of Fig. 1. An easy fix, if you place the last graphic in its own subfigure environment, give it an empty subcaption, and declare the main caption (for fig 2) outside the subfigure envt.